# Using tooltips with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to have tooltips in my paragraph text. A box with helper text should appear on hover.

I found the following code (I removed the hover to keep things simple):

```css
.para {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.tooltip1 {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">Todas estas questões, devidamente <span class="tooltip1">devidamente ponderadas <span class="tooltip-text1">Realizar o download dos testes para as avaliações formativas</span></span> levantam dúvidas sobre se a expansão dos mercados mundiais nos obriga à análise dos relacionamentos verticais entre as hierarquias</p>
```

These lines do the work but I don't understand how:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
```

Why does changing the negative margin have an effect on the width of the box?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to understand positionings in CSS (absolute and relative). When you give an absolute position to an element it searches the DOM for a first non-static parent (for this example relative (tooltip1 ) ) then it attaches itself to it as if that parent(tooltip1) were its whole screen. The margin-left: -60px is just tweak the location of the tootip-text but the absolute-relative position combo will keep it sticking to its parent.

More indepth: https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute

Answer (score 1):

negative margin has nothing to do with the width of the box. the negative margin value is the half of the width of tooltip so it becomes centered (because the `left` property is set to `50%`). you must specify the width of tooltip. also apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to it so border and padding are considered in the overall width of the tooltip and it becomes perfectly centered. I edited your code, check it out to see how it works.

```css
.para {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.tooltip1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text1 {
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;


----------


}
```

```html
<p class="para">Todas estas questões, devidamente <span class="tooltip1">devidamente ponderadas <span class="tooltip-text1">Realizar o download dos testes para as avaliações formativas</span></span> levantam dúvidas sobre se a expansão dos mercados mundiais nos obriga à análise dos relacionamentos verticais entre as hierarquias</p>
```